# Threaded PHP code is not deterministic

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I have the following code, running pthreads 2.0.10 with zts-php 5.6.25. The problem is, it should dump an array with the following values:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "def"
}
```

However sometimes the resulting array looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
}
```

And I'm baffled why is this happening. Maybe some basic thread related rules I'm missing, just can't seem to get my head around it. Any ideas?

```
<?
class LinkChecker extends Threaded 
{
    protected $complete;
    protected $urls;

    public $data = '';

    /**
    * @param array $urls Contains the urls to be checked
    */
    public function __construct($urls)
    {
        $this->complete = false;
        $this->urls = $urls;
    } //function

    public function run()
    {
        foreach($this->urls as $url)
        {
            //usleep(200000);
            $this->data .= $url;
            echo 'X';
        } //foreach

        $this->complete = true;
    } //function

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    } //function

    public function isGarbage() 
    {
        return $this->complete;
    } //function
} //LinkChecker


class LinkCheckerPool extends Pool
{
    public $data = array();
    public function process()
    {
        $lastcnt = null;
        // Run this loop as long as we have
        // jobs in the pool
        while (count($this->work) > 0) 
        {
            if ($lastcnt != count($this->work))
            {
                echo $lastcnt = count($this->work)."\n";
            } //if

            $this->collect(function (LinkChecker $task) 
            {
                // If a task was marked as done
                // collect its results
                if ( $task->isGarbage() )
                {
                    echo $task->getData();
                    //this is how you get your completed data back out [accessed by $pool->process()]
                    $this->data[] = $task->getData();
                } //if

                return $task->isGarbage();
            });
        } //while

        // All jobs are done
        // we can shutdown the pool
        $this->shutdown();
        return $this->data;
    } //function
} //class

$pool = new LinkCheckerPool(10);

$pool->submit( new LinkChecker(['a','b','c']) );
$pool->submit( new LinkChecker(['d','e','f']) );

$retArr = $pool->process();

var_dump($retArr); //return the array of results (and maybe errors)
```

Comment: There's a lot going on here. First of all there's no place where you alter `$this->work` and your `$this->data` is not modified in a thread-safe manner. My guess is you're bound to get problems when two threads try and modify `$this->data` concurrently

Comment: Threads 101: Thread unsafe entities are thread unsafe. Threads 102: An entity is thread unsafe until an effort has been made to make it thread safe.

Comment: threading threads gotta thread

Comment: Great and how can I adhere to the rules?